# How to traverse uncertain recursive path in xml using xslt.?

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml has following structure and I need to convert it  to html using XSLT. Can someone please help me with the xsl code for below. The output expected is [ [ ( 1 + 2 ) + 3 ] + 4 ] * 5 and   [ ( 1 + 2 ) + 3 ] + 4
Thanks in advance.

```
                    <FUNCTION>
                    <OPERATOR ID="MULTIPLY_OPERATOR">
                        <OPERATOR ID="ADD_OPERATOR" PAREN_WRAPPED="true">
                            <OPERATOR ID="ADD_OPERATOR">
                                <OPERATOR ID="ADD_OPERATOR">
                                    <x>1</x>
                                <y>2</y>
                                </OPERATOR>
                                <a>3</a>
                            </OPERATOR>
                             <b>4</b>
                        </OPERATOR>
                        <c>5</c>
                    </OPERATOR>

                    <OPERATOR ID="ADD_OPERATOR" PAREN_WRAPPED="true">
                        <OPERATOR ID="ADD_OPERATOR">
                            <OPERATOR ID="ADD_OPERATOR">
                                <x>1</x>
                                <y>2</y>
                            </OPERATOR>
                            <a>3</a>
                        </OPERATOR>
                        <b>4</b>
                    </OPERATOR>
                    </FUNCTION>
```

Comment: Please explain the required logic in words, instead of expecting us to deduce it from your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't understand in your example is that you have an `PAREN_WRAPPED="true"` attribute, however it seems, you want to have brackets or parentheses always and independent from the value of that attribute.

Well, anyway the following code should give you the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="foo" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="OPERATOR">
        <xsl:variable name="operator_symbol">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@ID = 'ADD_OPERATOR'">+</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@ID = 'MULTIPLY_OPERATOR'">*</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:call-template name="bracket_or_par"><xsl:with-param name="open_or_close" select="'open'"/></xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OPERATOR"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[string-length(name()) = 1]">
            <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = 'OPERATOR']">
                <xsl:value-of select="$operator_symbol"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$operator_symbol"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:call-template name="bracket_or_par"><xsl:with-param name="open_or_close" select="'close'"/></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="bracket_or_par">
        <xsl:param name="open_or_close"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="descendant::OPERATOR and ancestor::OPERATOR">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$open_or_close='open'">[</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$open_or_close='close'">]</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ancestor::OPERATOR and not(descendant::OPERATOR)">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$open_or_close='open'">(</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$open_or_close='close'">)</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Explanation: 
The stylesheet traverses all `OPERATOR` elements, first putting an open bracket/parenthesis around them, then processing all inner `OPERATOR` elements with ``OPERATOR`elements`.
Then it processes all direct child numerals of the current `OPERATOR`. The code assumes that all of your numerals are wrapped inside an element with a name consisting of just one char (`*[string-length(name()) = 1]`).
If there is an `OPERATOR` directly before the current numeral, the appropriate mathematical operator is put out. Then the value of the current numeral is put out (`<xsl:value-of select="."/>`). After that, for each numeral the mathematical operator is concatenated, except for the very last numeral inside one `OPERATOR`.

Comment: while I use this code i get an error in compiling the code in eclipse: FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
           :Error checking type of the expression 'FilterParentPath(variable-ref(bracket_or_par/result-tree), step("child", 32))'. Please suggest.

Comment: And also please explain the logic used in section starting with: <xsl:for-each select="*[string-length(name()) = 1]">.

Comment: See my edit above. I always underestimate the limitations of XSLT 1.0. Change to a newer version whenenver you can. With an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 my original code worked.

Comment: one issue i am facing is that i get en error: Named template bracket_or_par is not available even though it is existing... not sure what is the reason.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help here. I tested it with various XSLT processors and it did work. However,  the template `bracket_or_par` just makes the code a little bit more elegant. You can replace the template calls with the template content. That will do no harm, simply add some verbosity.

Comment: Thank you very much for instant help. I would request your help for one more of similar kind of issue. where the result is: 
( Attribute1 = 1143 ) AND ( Attribute2 = 5 ) for given XML structure.

<temp>
 <OPER ID="AND_OPERATOR">
  <OPER ID="ISEQUALTO_OPERATOR">
   <DATA>Attribute1</DATA>
   <STRING><![CDATA[1143]]></STRING>
  </OPER>
  <OPER ID="ISEQUALTO_OPERATOR">
   <DATA>Attribute2</DATA>
   <STRING><![CDATA[5]]></STRING>
  </OPER>
 </OPER>
</temp>

Comment: @Shweta You're welcome! However, I think in order to keep the site clean it would be better if you could accept the answer and open a new question for other issues.

Comment: sure.. I will do that

Comment: just wanted to confirm if the for-each loop after apply-templates traverses from outside node to inner node. Also, in a scenario if numerals are not wrapped inside one char, then is it correct to use child::node() ?

Comment: The for each loop only processes direct child nodes, inner `OPERATOR` nodes are processed with the preceding `apply-templates`. The problem with `child::node()` (or `node()` which is the same) as `@select` XPath expression inside for-each is that it will also select `OPERATOR` elements which is not what you want. You can try `node()[not(local-name='OPERATOR')]` however.